# Address Problems in LLVM Interpreter

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I'm using LLVM interpreter. I tried to find variables values by using ExecutionEngine.cpp and Execution.cpp. I could find current values, but I have another problem. The binary operations could be done with similar addresses. I think they use temp addresses, but why same ones? I need to make them different to get some results. 
To be more clear

Here are different instructions for different basic blocks, with there interpreting information I got.

First Instruction is:

```
About to interpret:   %BB1 = add i32 %4, 1
Basic Block Name: CBB1
 arg0:    %4 = load i32, i32* @BB1
 arg1:  i32 1
visitBinaryOperator
Source1 Current Input ::: 10
Source1 Current Address ::: 0x7fff4582cd90
Source1 [ 0, 41 ]
Source1 Current Input::: 1
Source1 Current Input ::: 10
Sourc2 Current Address::: 0x7fff4582cdc0
```

Second Instruction is

```
About to interpret:   %10 = add nsw i32 %9, %8
BasicBlock Name: CBB2
     arg0:    %9 = load i32, i32* %sum, align 4
     arg1:    %8 = load i32, i32* %7, align 4
visitBinaryOperator
Source1 Current Input ::: 0
Source1 Current Address ::: 0x7fff4582cd90
Source2 Current Input ::: 0
Source2 Current Address::: 0x7fff4582cdc0
```

Part of BasicBlock CBB2

```
  %8 = load i32, i32* %7, align 4
  %9 = load i32, i32* %sum, align 4
  %10 = add nsw i32 %9, %8
  store i32 %10, i32* %sum, align 4
```

I need to get some analysis using current and previous values for each instructions inputs and outputs.

I got the values from function `Interpreter::visitBinaryOperator`:

```
ExecutionContext &SF = ECStack.back();
Type *Ty    = I.getOperand(0)->getType();
GenericValue Src1 = getOperandValue(I.getOperand(0), SF);
GenericValue Src2 = getOperandValue(I.getOperand(1), SF);
GenericValue R;   // Result
```

Getting addresses `y1, y2, r`  and values `v1, v2, rv`:

```
uint8_t *y1 = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(
               const_cast<uint64_t *>(Src1.IntVal.getRawData()));
int v1 = *reinterpret_cast<int *>(y1);
uint8_t *y2 = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(
               const_cast<uint64_t *>(Src2.IntVal.getRawData()));
int v2 = *reinterpret_cast<int *>(y2);
uint8_t *r = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(
               const_cast<uint64_t *>(R.IntVal.getRawData()));
int rv = *reinterpret_cast<int *>(r);
```

I have another suggestion, if I could not solve the problem for `add` instruction, could I use the `load` instructions before `add` and `store` instruction after `add`, to get my results. I could already get them individually with valid results, but how to be connected to be arguments for the binary operation.

Comment: Could you, please, expand on how do you get the addresses, and also show the code you analyze?

Comment: I have edited the post, please check